# Why to store User Information getting from JWT token in Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I save the information (JWT payload) inside local storage in order to maintain the user session. But I have seen many articles and videos where people save token information in local storage or cookies as well as in redux global state. I understand that they save this information in redux because to use this info. throughout the application.
My question here is. Why are they saving that information in redux when this can be fetched from local storage or cookies any time and it is available throughout the application.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Saving `jwt` in `localStorage` means saving them in computer storage. This is useful if you want user to be logged in whenever he/she open the browser. However, fetching data from `localStorage` requires memory interaction.

If you save data in `redux`, as `redux` store is just a Javascript object, it's much faster. In most cases, whenever we use `jwt`, we need to update it again as `jwt` token includes expire date. And we need to add them as a header very often. Thefore, saving them in redux is for speed problem, I guess.